# How to display a window of lines in a .txt file in batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file

So I'm building a messaging program in batch (I know, it's newbish) and the program takes user input, puts it in my .txt file `log.txt`, and types it on the screen. I want the output to look like this...

```
Title
----------------------
contents
of
the
file
here
----------------------
User input here>>
```

This may seem simple, but the file will be constantly updated by users and I want the program to only display a range of lines to keep that message area stays the same size. I found a simple program to display specific lines, but I can't make them move down one line each time `log.txt` is changed. Here it is:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
set lines=1
set curr=1
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type bob.txt') do (
    for %%b in (!lines!) do (
        if !curr!==%%b echo %%a
    )
    set /a "curr = curr + 1"
)
endlocal
```

(By the way, this program is called `lines.bat`. I just `call` it in cmd to test it.)

Answer (score 0):

To return a defined number of lines starting from a certain line number, you can do the following:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions

rem define the (path to the) text file here:
set "TEXT_FILE=log.txt"
rem define the line number here:
set /A "LINE_NUMBER=1"
rem define the number of lines here:
set /A "LINE_COUNT=5"

set /A "LINE_LIMIT=LINE_NUMBER+LINE_COUNT-1"
for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ('findstr /N /R "^" "%TEXT_FILE%"') do (
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    set "LINE=%%L"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=:" %%N in ("!LINE!") do set "LNUM=%%N"
    set "LINE=!LINE:*:=!"
    if !LNUM! GEQ !LINE_NUMBER! (
        if !LNUM! LEQ !LINE_LIMIT! (
            echo !LINE!
        )
    )
    endlocal
    endlocal
)
endlocal
```

The `findstr` command with the `/R` `"^"` search pattern returns all lines. The `findstr` switch `/N` lets every line precede with a line number (starting from `1`) and a colon. The `:` is used to split the line in two parts: the first part representing the line number is checked whether it is in the range to be returned; the second part is the original line of text which is simply output in case. Even empty lines are taken into account.

You might ask why not simply using the above mentioned `:` as a `delims` delimiter option for `for /F`, but this would cause problems with lines of text starting with `:`.

The toggling of [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is necessary to avoid trouble with special characters like `!`, for instance.

---

To return the last defined number of lines, the following approach can be used:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions

rem define the (path to the) text file here:
set "TEXT_FILE=log.txt"
rem define the number of lines here:
set /A "LINE_COUNT=5"

for /F "tokens=1 delims=:" %%L in ('findstr /N /R "^" "%TEXT_FILE%"') do (
    set /A "LINE_SKIP=%%L"
)
set /A "LINE_SKIP-=LINE_COUNT"
if %LINE_SKIP% GTR 0 (
    set "LINE_SKIP=skip^=%LINE_SKIP%^ "
) else (
    set "LINE_SKIP="
)
for /F %LINE_SKIP%delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ('findstr /N /R "^" "%TEXT_FILE%"') do (
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    set "LINE=%%L"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "LINE=!LINE:*:=!"
    echo !LINE!
    endlocal
    endlocal
)
endlocal
```

Again, the `findstr /N /R "^"` command is used. But here, we have an additional `for /F` loop first, which merely counts the number of lines in the text file, extracting the line number preceded by `findstr`. The second `for /F` loop is quite similar to the above approach, but a dynamic `skip` option is introduced, so that the loop starts iterating through the last lines only; the rest is almost the same as above, except that the conditions concerning the current line number have been removed.

I know I could do the counting of lines also by using `find /C /V ""` rather than looping through the `findstr /N /R "^"` output, but if there are one or more empty lines at the end of the file, `find` returns a number one less as the `findstr` method, so I went for `findstr` consistently.

Also here, [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is toggled to avoid trouble with the `!` character.

Comment: I'm a bit confused... Do these scripts print a range of line numbers? What I want to do is (e.g.) print lines 1-5, and when a new line is added, 2-6, then 3-7, and so forth.

Comment: Yes; the first one prints a predefined range, the second one the last number of lines, and it implicitly demonstrates how to determine the total number of lines... so you also need to detect the modification of the text file by the script??

Comment: Yes, I want it to scroll down when the file is added to.

Comment: There is nothing like an event feature in command prompt that triggers something in case a file is modified... so you can only put the script in a loop, insert a `cls` at the beginning and a `timeout` at the end...

Comment: Is there a way that I can access the date/time when it was last modified and assign that to a variable?

Comment: `for %I in ("log.txt") do set "DATE_TIME=%~tI"` (use `%%` instead of `%` within a batch file); note that the returned date/time value does not contain the seconds, and that it is of region-dependent format...